# Create jQuery Mobile Menu Using #Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please point me to where I can go to find info on how to create a mobile menu (drop list) for the code bellow? All the tutorials that I have found has been on switching pages, nothing for filters such as bellow. I am using the isotop plugin to navigate through my site.

```
<!-- SMOOTH MENU DIV -->
    <div id="nav-button"> </div>
    <nav id="smooth-menu" role="navigation" class="main-nav-links responsive-nav">
        <ul id="filters" data-option-key="filter">
            <li><a href="#filter=.home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#filter=.about">About Danielle</a></li>
            <li id="one"><a href="javascript: history.go(1)">My Work</a>
                <ul class="second-level">
                    <li><a href="#filter=.kids-and-family">Kids and Family</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#filter=.babies">Babies</a></li>                       
                    <li class="last"><a href="#filter=.seniors">Seniors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="two"><a href="javascript: history.go(1)">Info</a>
                <ul class="second-level">
                    <li><a href="#filter=.session-fees">Session Fees</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#filter=.finished-art">Finished Art</a></li>                       
                    <li class="last"><a href="#filter=.about-your-session">About Your Session</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#filter=.contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>          
    <!-- end nav -->
```

Comment: This fiddle might help you take a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/nQTTC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an alternative solution. I went with a different menu.